# How do I write an awk print command in a loop?

Tags: shell, loops, unix, printing, awk

I would like to write a loop creating various output files with the first column of each input file, respectively.

So I wrote

```
for i in $(\ls -d /home/*paired.isoforms.results)
do
awk -F"\t" {print $1}' $i > $i.transcript_ids.txt
done
```

As an example if there were 5 files in the home directory named

```
A_paired.isoforms.results
B_paired.isoforms.results
C_paired.isoforms.results
D_paired.isoforms.results
E_paired.isoforms.results
```

I would like to print the first column of each of these files into a seperate output file, i.e. I would like to have 5 output files called

```
A.transcript_ids.txt
B.transcript_ids.txt
C.transcript_ids.txt
D.transcript_ids.txt
E.transcript_ids.txt
```

or any other name as long as it is 5 different names and I can still link them back to the original files.

I understand, that there is a problem with the double usage of $ in both the awk and the loop command, but I don't know how to change that.

Is it possible to write a command like this in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
for file in /home/*paired.isoforms.results
do
    base=${file##*/}
    base=${base%%_*}
    awk -F"\t" '{print $1}' $file > $base.transcript_ids.txt
done
```

I assume that there can be spaces in the first field since you set the delimiter explicitly to tab.  This runs `awk` once per file.  There are ways to do it running `awk` once for all files, but I'm not convinced the benefit is significant.  You could consider using `cut` instead of `awk '{print $1}'`, too.  Note that using `ls` as you did is less satisfactory than using globbing directly; it runs foul of file names with oddball characters (spaces, tabs, etc) in the name.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and useful advice. The script worked great! Also thanks for the additional information. Since I mostly try and adapt code that I find elsewhere to work for my data, I appreciate the general information!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that entirely in awk:

```
awk -F"\t" '{split(FILENAME,a,"_"); out=a[1]".transcript_ids.txt"; print $1 > out}' *_paired.isoforms.results
```

If your input files don't have names as indicated in the question, you'd have to `split` on something else ( as well as use a different pattern match for the input files ).

---

My original answer is actually doing extra name resolution every time something is printed.  Here's a version that only updates the output filename when `FILENAME` changes:

```
awk -F"\t" 'FILENAME!=lf{split(FILENAME,a,"_"); out=a[1]".transcript_ids.txt"; lf=FILENAME} {print $1 > out}' *_paired.isoforms.results
```

Comment: Would you let me know why you un-chose my answer?  It wasn't checked long enough for the reputation tracker to catch it either way - just curious.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am new to this forum, so I didn't realize you can only accept one answer even if both worked fine. While your code solved the example I had given, I ended up going with the second answer, because it put the files in the directory I was working in (I know I hadn't asked for that) and also, because I could use the newly learned addition to my loop knowledge in a different context as well. I still appreciated your answer though and it did solve the posted problem. Cheers!